# Why are lights on 15 amp circuits and receptacles on 20 amp?

Tags: circuit-breaker

I'm wondering about the logic behind 15 amp vs 20 amp.  Why isn't everything 20 amp if it is considered safe?

If a light circuit shorts, what difference does it make it if trips at 15amp vs 20 amp?

Comment: Because for 20 amp circuits you need heavier wiring (at least 12 gauge) which is more expensive, harder to work with and uses more resources to make, none of which is necessary for most lighting circuits and most outlets (except bath, kitchen, laundry and the like).

Answer (score 5):

Breakers protect wiring and connections. Most lighting circuits are done with #14 wire, which is adequate for the duty it performs. To prevent overheating (fire risk), 15A breakers are required by code for most circuits using #14 AWG wire. Lighter wire and other components are less expensive and easier to work with.

Many power tools, appliances, and other devices draw at or above 15A at startup or under load. It's often desirable to have more current capacity there than you'd need in a lighting circuit. 20A circuits are typically wired with #12 AWG wire to handle the additional current safely.

Simply put, each circuit has a different purpose. It's not just about short circuit protection, but available current load.

Comment: +1 The handle rating has little to do with short-circuits, and everything to do with circuit "capacity".

Answer (score 4):

It matters if there's mere overload but less than a short.  14 gauge wire cannot carry 20A safely.  So why use 14 gauge?  The answer is you are corralled into it by market forces: it makes for easier, faster, cheaper work.  Here are the factors that come into that.

**Stranded vs Solid-core.**  Stranded wire bends much easier, but costs 5-10% more.  Solid-core is stiffer, and 12 gauge can be a real wrestling match in a small junction box.

**Sheathing/grouping.**  Wire must be grouped and protected. Conduit is very hard to install, but easily expanded later by pulling more single wires.  Non-Metallic NM (aka Romex) is 3-5 wires permanently bundled together.

**Wire size**, typically 14 or 12 gauge, determines ampacity.  In solid wire, heavier wire is obviously stiffer. And more costly - 12 gauge NM is 50% more -- however for conduit, 12 gauge THHN is only 20% more (go figure).  NM only comes in solid-core, so being multiple conductors, gets quite stiff - even moreso with 12 gauge.

**Connection to devices** can be either screw terminals or "back-stabs".  Screw terminals are considered more reliable but a lot slower work, and are easiest with solid-core wire.  In back-stabs, you jab a short length of stripped wire into a hole rated only for certain sizes of wire, typically 14ga only and solid-core only.

**Purpose** decides wire gauge too.  For residential lighting circuits, 14 gauge is sufficient, especially with the new, efficient lighting.

So now we can talk about the business side.

In residential work, NM is much faster (cheaper) than conduit. That necessitates solid wire, where 12 gauge is heavy and stiff to wrestle into junction boxes.  14 gauge is cheaper than 12, and it works with backstabs instead of laboriously twisting a U-hook for screw terminals, which adds up to fewer billed hours and more profit on the house. And that's what it's all about.

Houses sell on five things: **Location, location, location, features and price.**  12ga, screw terminals and conduit are nice, but cost money and add *no sellable features* and thus *no retail value* to the house. So your builder wouldn't do it unless you were locked in, and your lender wouldn't lend on the additional cost.

So that's why 14 gauge, and thus, 15 amps.

Answer (score 0):

It is not too complicated.  Breakers are generally designed to protect the wiring, not the appliance or light.

Lighting circuits, nonlinear loads, and non-inductive motor loads generally have a higher total wattage consumption on average than inductive motor loads.

Inductive motor loads have startup and stop/fault loads.  These can peak up to 6x or more than the normal current load of the motor.  But again, breakers are generally designed to protect the wiring.